# How to initialize derived class members when using C++11 inheriting constructors?

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance, constructor

There's something I don't understand about the new C++11 feature of inheriting the base class's constructors with:

```
using BaseClass::BaseClass;
```

I thought this was a handy feature, but now I have a derived class that has additional members, and it seems I have to rewrite the constructor if I want to initialise the derived class's members:

```
struct BaseClass
{
    BaseClass(char* name, int intVal, float floatVal) : name(name), intVal(intVal), floatVal(floatVal) {}
    char* name;
    int intVal;
    float floatVal;
};

struct DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    using BaseClass::BaseClass;
    int additionalMember;
};
```

Do I have to manually rewrite the constructor and pass the values to the base's constructor, then initialise the additional member?

```
struct DerivedClass : BaseClass
    {
        DerivedClass(char* name, int intVal, float floatVal) : BaseClass(name, intVal, floatVal), additionalMember(7) {}
        int additionalMember;
    };
```

If so, the use of this new feature of inheriting constructors seems really limited.

So do I have to rewrite the constructors each time?

Comment: Yes, you do have to rewrite the constructors each time. Same as you would in virtually any other language. You might be able to get by with *aggregate initialization*, but that requires you to never define a constructor for any of your classes and subclasses (which would then make it implicitly-declared), and that may not be a reasonable option for your use-case.

Comment: What would you expect?

Comment: @n.m. I'm new to this feature. I firstly thought it was an excellent feature. Then when I came across this issue I thought it's really limited, as usually when making subclasses you're adding features (members) that then need to be initialised.

Comment: @TitoneMaurice: How is the base class constructor supposed to know how to initialise your derived class members? That's not a logical expectation.

Comment: @TitoneMaurice quite often one only adds or overrides functions, not data members. At other times new data members will have acceptable default constructors or in-class initialisers.

Answer (score 2):

You could use default value:

```
struct DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    using BaseClass::BaseClass;
    int additionalMember = 0;
};
```

However if you need the value passed from the user of your class you will have to provide the constructor for `DerviedClass`.